# Ruby if/elsif/else

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to write a game. In the following code, it keeps skipping to the bottom `else` even if a valid integer is entered. Why?

```
puts 'You will be O\'s and I will be X\'s'
puts
puts '1,2,X'
puts '4,5,6'
puts '7,8,9'
puts 
puts 'Your move...'
puts
moveOne = gets.chomp
if moveOne == 5
    puts =  '1,2,X'
    puts =  '4,O,6'
    puts =  'X,8,9'
elsif moveOne == 1
    puts  = 'O,2,X'
    puts  = '4,5,6'
    puts = 'X,8,9'
elsif moveOne == 7
    puts  = 'X,2,X'
    puts  = '4,5,6'
    puts  = 'O,8,9'
elsif moveOne == 9
    puts  = 'X,2,X'
    puts  = '4,5,6'
    puts  = '7,8,O'
elsif moveOne == 2
    puts  = '1,O,X'
    puts  = '4,X,6'
    puts  = '7,8,9'
elsif moveOne == 4
    puts  = '1,2,X'
    puts  = 'O,X,6'
    puts  = '7,8,9'
elsif moveOne == 6
    puts  = '1,2,X'
    puts  = '4,X,O'
    puts  = '7,8,9'
elsif moveOne == 8
    puts  = '1,2,X'
    puts  = '4,X,6'
    puts  = '7,O,9'
else
    puts'please enter a number!'
end
puts
puts 'Your move again'
```

Comment: nick2653, best to make your example code as concise as possible to illustrate your problem.  Here, all you need is `if moveOne == 5; puts = '1,2,X'; else; puts "Please enter a number"; end` and ask why the else clause s executed when you enter 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because chomp is giving you a string, not an integer.

```
moveOne = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Comment: And `gets` is giving you a string, so you can simply use `.to_i` without the chomp as it will take care of the newline automatically.

Comment: thanks Andy and vgoff! quick question for you vgoff I removed the chomp like you said. What is the syntax to get the three lines to return on top of one another? I tried moveOne = gets.to_i
if moveOne == 5
    puts =  '1,2,X'
    puts =  '4,O,6'
    puts =  'X,8,9'

Comment: Don't assign anything to `puts`, just `puts 1, 2, 3`

Comment: You could just do `moveOne = gets.to_i`

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `gets.chomp` returns a **String**, not an **Integer**.  if you do:

`"a".to_i` --> 0 , Which your program might think the user has actually entered a 0.

So, first, you want to make sure that what the user has entered is a number character, even though it's of class **String**.

Here is what you could do:

1 - Create a method that will check if a String is number-like:

```
def is_a_number?(s)
  s.to_s.match(/\A[+-]?\d+?(\.\d+)?\Z/) == nil ? false : true 
end
```

2 - If it is number like, just cast it to integer using `.to_i`

So, your code would look like:

```
moveOne = gets.chomp
if is_a_number?(moveOne)
  number_entered = moveOne.to_i
  if number_entered == 5
    ...
  elsif number_entered == 1
    ...
else
  puts "enter a number..."
end
```